# href not waiting for function to return before redirecting

Tags: javascript, html, css, animation

I'm trying to make some animations to move some elements to make movement between pages smoother. For some reason when I click the link I'm redirected to the page before the animation plays out.

Below is the HTML for the link

```
<div id='Logo' class="logopos"><a href="{% url 'Home' %}" ><img class="image" src="{% static 'assets/Icon.png'%}" alt="Logo"/></a></div>
  <div id="Menu" class="list">
    <a href="" class="base-button" onclick='move()'>Home</a>
    <a onclick='move()' href="{% url 'Portfolio' %}" class="base-button">Portfolio</a>
    <a href="{% url 'About' %}" class="base-button">About</a>    
    <a href="{% url 'Contact' %}" class="base-button">Contact</a> 
  </div>
```

Below is the animation js function

```
function move() {
    var logo = document.getElementById("Logo");
    var menu = document.getElementById("Menu");

    logo.animate([
    { 'left': '50vw' , 'top': '25vh'},
    { 'left': '5vw', 'top':'7.5vh'}
    ],
    { duration: 1000});

    menu.animate([
        {'left' : '50vw', 'top' :'40vh', 'width': '10vw'},
        {'left' : '0vw', 'top' :'5vh', 'width': '7.5vw'}
    ],
    {duration: 1000});

    logo.style.left = "5vw"
    logo.style.top = "7.5vh"
    menu.style.left = '0vw'
    menu.style.top = '5vh'
    menu.style.width= '7.5vw'
    return true;
}
```

Below is the css for the relevant elemants

```
.list {
    position: absolute;
    top: 40vh;
    left: 50vw;
}

.base-button {
    display: block;
    background: rgba(190, 193, 197, 0.1);
    background-clip: padding-box;
    text-align: center;
    color: #bec1c5;
    border: none;
    width: 10vw;
    height: 3vh;
    background-clip: text;
    padding: 5px;
    margin-left: -5vw;
    margin-top: -5px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 10px;
    font-size: 20px;
    font-family: Adoring;
}

.image {
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    margin: auto;
    width: 7.5vw;
    margin-left: -3.75vw;
    margin-top: -3.75vh;
    opacity: 0.75;
}

.logopos {
    position: absolute;
    top: 25vh;
    left: 50vw;
}
```

I have tried using `e.preventDefault()` but this just stops the subsequent page from loading altogether.

I've also tried to put the animation in a while loop and to break after animation is complete and return, also no dice.

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: _"I have tried using e.preventDefault() but this just stops the subsequent page from loading altogether."_ - you will have to implement the part of going to the target URL after your animation has finished, yourself, in JavaScript. There is no "delay" for following links in HTML, you either let it happen immediately without interruption, or you "cancel" it altogether. And in the latter case, you then have to perform the switch to a different URL actively yourself.

Answer (score 0):

You must stop redirecting action by returning false in onclick by:

```
onclick="btnOnClick(this);return false;"
```

Full example:

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Test Page</title>
</head>
<body>

  <script> 
    function btnOnClick(elm){
      console.log(elm.href);
      
      // here do your code
      //
      
      // eventually on the end:
      
      location.href = elm.href;
      
      return;
    }
  </script>

  Link:
  <a href="#test" class="base-button" onclick="btnOnClick(this);return false;">Home</a>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I've made the function return false and added the location.href but still no luck

Answer (score 0):

Don't add link in href, instead when you have done with animation, you can redirect to another page by js like this
`window.location.href = "https://example.com";`

add this line in the move function to redirect to next page.

Comment: I've added this to the end of my JS and running e.preventDefault() but the animation still doesn't seem to complete.